# Looking for a lightweight laptop thats under 2 KG

Tags: laptop, lightweight

I'm looking for a lightweight laptop (under 2 KG or preferable 1.5 KG) thats not too hard on the pocket. I was thinking of a Sony VAIO but I wanted to know if I have any better and/or cheaper options.

A *Core 2 Duo* or similar processor with 2gigs RAM should be good; and the basics like a DVD writer, WiFi and an inbuilt webcam.

Has anyone come across websites that let you run such parametric computer searches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a specific recommendation of a computer, but Newegg.com lets you [search by weight](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=Property&Subcategory=32&Description=&Type=&N=2034940032&srchInDesc=&MinPrice=&MaxPrice=&PropertyCodeValue=445%3A14141&PropertyCodeValue=445%3A14142&PropertyCodeValue=445%3A14143).

Comment: They have an excellent "power" search that lets you define every conceivable parameter. see http://www.newegg.com/Product/PowerSearch.aspx?Submit=Property&N=2034940032&SubCategory=32&GASearch=1

Comment: Yep, that's where I found the weight option.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of one off-hand, but [Notebook Review](http://www.notebookreview.com) will allow you to perform a search to find the laptop that you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Lenovo X series.

[Compare Models](http://shop.lenovo.com/SEUILibrary/controller/e/web/LenovoPortal/en_US/catalog.workflow:expandcategory?current-catalog-id=12F0696583E04D86B9B79B0FEC01C087&current-category-id=135A781CA29B4ECB9ADAD8E72CF6FD61&tab=3#tab-container-5)

Comment: X models are not so cheap, but you might consider second hand. I own an X61 (http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Category:X61) and I'm very happy with ! Here's some good information about X Series :http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Category:X_Series

Answer (score 1):

If one is willing to take a laptop without a DVD writer, you can get a [Macbook Air](http://www.notebookreview.com/price/product.asp?productFamilyID=1126&pid=17524) for just 1000 dollars plus tax. Also, there is a drive accessory for it however i am unsure what type of drive it is,

Comment: I think you're missing a 0. `;)`

Comment: Yep. If only i could get one for that much... :D

Answer (score 0):

The [13inch Macbook](http://www.apple.com/macbookpro/specs-13inch.html) weights 2.04kg. Although there are probably cheaper and lighter alternatives out there, the chassis for the Macbook is aluminium, so this might have to be a good contender